# getting multiple values enclosed with brackets from a string

Tags: java

Given a string: 
How can I printout all values enclosed in brackets from a string in one line?

```
String str = "java programming (for)all (beginners) is (very) interesting"; 
String values= StringUtils.substringBetween(str,"(",")");
System.out.print(values);
```

What I need is: for beginners very
But i'm only getting one value: for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the documentation [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#substringsBetween(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), i would say you are using the wrong function.

```
String[] values= StringUtils.substringsBetween(str,"(",")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading up on `substringBetween` [it says it](http://libcommons-lang-java.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.0/classorg_1_1apache_1_1commons_1_1lang_1_1StringUtils_f47b956d27f446d016888970cd3ce187.html)

> Gets the String that is nested in between two instances of the same String.

I read that as it only does it once. I.e. once it finds the first string between the brackets, it's 'done' and returns it, without continuing. Notice how it's return:

```
String values ....
```

is a `String`, not a string array `String[]`.

There would be two ways to solve the problem. First, you could do `substringBetween` on the next bit of string, and repeat until you ran out. Or you could do it a different way completely. Given that the `substringBetween` does not give you any positional information (i.e. it's found the substring at character 12 etc) it wouldn't be very easy to repeat the operation, so I'd suggest you use a different method (maybe start with `String.split("(")` ?)

Or as Till says, use substringsBetween which returns an array of all strings. Does feel like it's cheating a little if this is a homework assignment though! Worth giving it a go with a for loop yourself or something to try write your own `substringsBetween` function.